# ¿Como borrar la información de las cajas al momento de dar en guardar?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tengo un problema al momento de dar clic en el botón crear  necesito que se restablezca  el  inputText   y quede vacío  pero no lo consigo, he probado con  update="principal" pero tampoco lo logro, alguien sabe que le falta a mi código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código facelets

```xhtml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Tipo Pago</title>
</h:head>
<ui:composition template="templates/commonLayout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="tipodepago">
        <h:outputText value="!!!!Gestión tipo de pago!!!" />
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="contenido">
        <h:form id="principal">

            <p:growl id="capaMensajes" globalOnly="false" showSumary="true"
                showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />


            <p:fieldset class="main" legend="Formulario Tipo de pago"
                toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500" style="width:60%">

                <p:toolbar>
                    <f:facet name="right">


                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-refresh" value="Limpiar" type="reset">
                            <p:ajax update="principal" type="reset" />
                        </p:commandButton>

                        <p:commandButton value="Crear" id="cbCrear"
                            action="#{tipodepagoBean.crear}"

                            update=":tabla:idTablatipopago,pgTipodepago"  icon="ui-icon-disk">

                            </p:commandButton>

                        <p:blockUI block="principal" trigger="cbCrear">
                             Cargando<br />
                            <p:graphicImage
                                url="images/ajax-loader.gif.pagespeed.ce.VLDv-_-pOi.gif"
                                width="80%" />
                        </p:blockUI>
                        <p:commandButton value="Actualizar" id="cbActualizar"
                            action="#{tipodepagoBean.actualizar()}"
                            update=":tabla:idTablatipopago,pgTipodepago"
                            icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w">
                            <p:confirm header="Actualizar Registro"
                                message="¿Está seguro que desea actualizar el tipo de pago?"
                                icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade"
                            hideEffect="explode">
                            <p:commandButton value="Aceptar" type="button"
                                style="font-size:12px" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes"
                                icon="ui-icon-check" />
                            <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" type="button"
                                style="font-size:12px" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no"
                                icon="ui-icon-close" />
                            <p:blockUI block="principal" trigger="cbActualizar">
                             Cargando<br />
                                <p:graphicImage
                                    url="images/ajax-loader.gif.pagespeed.ce.VLDv-_-pOi.gif"
                                    width="80%" />
                            </p:blockUI>
                        </p:confirmDialog>

                        <p:commandButton value="Eliminar" id="cbEliminar"
                            action="#{tipodepagoBean.eliminar()}"
                            update=":tabla:idTablatipopago,pgTipodepago" icon="ui-icon-trash">
                            <p:confirm header="Eliminar Registro"
                                message="¿Está seguro que desea eliminar el medio de pago?"
                                icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                        </p:commandButton>

                        <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade"
                            hideEffect="explode">
                            <p:commandButton value="Aceptar" type="button"
                                style="font-size:12px" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes"
                                icon="ui-icon-check" />
                            <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" type="button"
                                style="font-size:12px" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no"
                                icon="ui-icon-close" />

                            <p:blockUI block="principal" trigger="cbEliminar">
                             Cargando<br />
                                <p:graphicImage
                                    url="images/ajax-loader.gif.pagespeed.ce.VLDv-_-pOi.gif"
                                    width="80%" />
                            </p:blockUI>
                        </p:confirmDialog>
                    </f:facet>

                </p:toolbar>

                <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="pgTipodepago" style="width:100%"
                    align="center">

                    <h:outputLabel />

                    <h:inputHidden id="itCodigo" style="width:100%">
                    </h:inputHidden>


                    <h:outputLabel for="itDescripcion"
                        value="Descripción tipo de pago:" />

                    <p:inputText id="itDescripcion" style="width:50%"
                        value="#{tipodepagoBean.nvDescripcion}" maxlength="50"
                        required="true" requiredMessage="La descripción es requerida">
                        <p:message for="itDescripcion" display="icon" />

                        <p:tooltip for="itDescripcion"
                            value="Campo para ingresar la Descripción de tipo de pago"
                            hideEffect="explode" />
                    </p:inputText>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:fieldset>
        </h:form>
        <p:fieldset collapsed="true" class="main"
            legend="Listado de tipos de pago" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500"
            style="width:60%">

            <h:form id="tabla">

                <p:dataTable var="tipodepago" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="100"
                    responsive="true" id="idTablatipopago"
                    value="#{tipodepagoBean.listatipodepago}" widgetVar="tablatipopago"
                    selectionMode="single" selection="#{tipodepagoBean.tipodepago}"
                    rowKey="#{tipodepago.inCodigo}" rows="5" paginator="true"
                    paginatorPosition="bottom" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                    draggableColumns="true"
                    emptyMessage="No existe Descripción de tipo de pago para mostrar">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h1></h1>
                        <p:commandButton id="toggler" type="button" value="Filtrar"
                            style="float" icon="ui-icon-calculator" />
                        <p:columnToggler datasource="idTablatipopago" trigger="toggler" />

                    </f:facet>
                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":principal:pgTipodepago" />


                    <p:column filterBy="#{tipodepago.inCodigo}"
                        sortBy="#{tipodepago.inCodigo}" headerText=" Codigo tipo de pago"
                        filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <h:outputText value="#{tipodepago.inCodigo}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column filterBy="#{tipodepago.nvDescripcion}"
                        sortBy="#{tipodepago.nvDescripcion}" headerText=" Descripcion"
                        filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <h:outputText value="#{tipodepago.nvDescripcion}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
        </p:fieldset>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

ManageBean

```
package co.edu.remington.restaurantes.controller;
/*
Esta clase define los objetos para la clase tipo de pago
@author: Sebastian Osorio Zuluaga
*/
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.push.EventBus;
import org.primefaces.push.EventBusFactory;

import co.edu.remington.restaurantes.entities.TblTipoPago;
import co.edu.remington.restaurantes.servicios.TipopagoService;

@ManagedBean(name = "tipodepagoBean")
@ViewScoped
public class TipodepagoBean extends GenericBB implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9026128169796230967L;
    // definición de atributos y entidades
    TipopagoService tipodepagoService;
    private int incodigo;
    private String nvDescripcion;
    private List<TblTipoPago> listatipodepago;
    private boolean esconderCodigo = false;
    private TblTipoPago tipodepago;

    // constructor ProductoBean por defecto
    public TipodepagoBean() {
        tipodepagoService = (TipopagoService) getServive(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "tipodepagoService");
        listatipodepago = tipodepagoService.lista();
    }

    // Metodo crear para tipo de pago
    public void crear() {
        try {
            tipodepagoService = (TipopagoService) getServive(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "tipodepagoService");
            TblTipoPago tipopago = new TblTipoPago();
            tipopago.setInCodigo(incodigo);
            tipopago.setNvDescripcion(nvDescripcion);
            TblTipoPago RTblTipoPago = tipodepagoService.add(tipopago);
            // se valida que RTblTipoPago sea diferente a null
            if (RTblTipoPago != null) {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Exito Se ingresó el tipo de pago de forma adecuada.", nvDescripcion));
                listatipodepago = tipodepagoService.lista();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error al intentar guardar en la base de datos ", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    // Metodo buscar para tipo de pago
    public void buscar() {

        tipodepagoService = (TipopagoService) getServive(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "tipodepagoService");
        TblTipoPago tipopago = new TblTipoPago();
        tipopago.setInCodigo(incodigo);
        tipodepagoService.get(tipopago);
    }

    // Metodo actualizar para tipo de pago
    public void actualizar() {
        try {
            tipodepagoService = (TipopagoService) getServive(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "tipodepagoService");
            tipodepago.setNvDescripcion(nvDescripcion);
            TblTipoPago RTblTipoPago = tipodepagoService.update(tipodepago);
            // se valida que RTblTipoPago sea diferente a null
            if (RTblTipoPago != null) {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Exito! se Actualizó el tipo de pago de forma adecuada.", nvDescripcion));
                listatipodepago = tipodepagoService.lista();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error al intentar Actualizar en la base de datos ", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    // Metodo eliminar para tipo de pago
    public void eliminar() {
        try {
            tipodepagoService = (TipopagoService) getServive(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "tipodepagoService");
            int retorno = tipodepagoService.delete(tipodepago);

            if (retorno == 1) {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Exito se borro el tipo de pago de forma adecuada.", nvDescripcion));
                listatipodepago = tipodepagoService.lista();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error al intentar Actualizar en la base de datos ", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    // Se generan los geters y seters para la clase tipodepagoBean con el fin de traer o modificar información

    public int getIncodigo() {
        return incodigo;
    }

    public void setIncodigo(int incodigo) {
        this.incodigo = incodigo;
    }

    public String getNvDescripcion() {
        return nvDescripcion;
    }

    public void setNvDescripcion(String nvDescripcion) {
        this.nvDescripcion = nvDescripcion;
    }

    public boolean isEsconderCodigo() {
        return esconderCodigo;
    }

    public void setEsconderCodigo(boolean esconderCodigo) {
        this.esconderCodigo = esconderCodigo;
    }

    public List<TblTipoPago> getListatipodepago() {
        return listatipodepago;
    }

    public void setListatipodepago(List<TblTipoPago> listatipodepago) {
        this.listatipodepago = listatipodepago;
    }

    public TblTipoPago getTipodepago() {
        return tipodepago;
    }

    public void setTipodepago(TblTipoPago tipodepago) {
        this.tipodepago = tipodepago;
    }

    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        tipodepago = (TblTipoPago) event.getObject();

    }

    public void notificarPUSH() {

        String summary = "Nuevo Elemento";
        String detail = "Se agrego a la lista";
        String CHANNEL = "/notify";

        EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
        eventBus.publish(CHANNEL, new FacesMessage(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml3(summary), StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml3(detail)));
    }

}
```

Comment: Es muy probable que el problema esté en el scope de tu managed bean que usas. Favor de colocar el código relevante del managed bean para el análisis respectivo.

Comment: Hola Luiggi Mendoza ya agregué el manageBean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puesto que tu bean tiene un alcance `@ViewScoped`, se creará una instancia del bean que estará viva mientras que el usuario esté interactuando en la misma vista (página). Dado esto, luego de usar las variables que sirven para interactuar con el usuario (aquellas variables que asocias a tus componentes usando `#{}`), deberás limpiarlas manualmente para reflejar que los campos están vacíos o deseleccionados.

Dicho esto, en tu método `crear` deberías re inicializar las variables que usas para la información de tu UI a modo de limpiar sus valores y que queden "vacíos". Por ejemplo:

```
public void crear() {
    try {
        tipodepagoService = (TipopagoService) getServive(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "tipodepagoService");
        TblTipoPago tipopago = new TblTipoPago();
        tipopago.setInCodigo(incodigo);
        tipopago.setNvDescripcion(nvDescripcion);
        TblTipoPago RTblTipoPago = tipodepagoService.add(tipopago);
        // se valida que RTblTipoPago sea diferente a null
        if (RTblTipoPago != null) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Exito Se ingresó el tipo de pago de forma adecuada.", nvDescripcion));
            listatipodepago = tipodepagoService.lista();
        }

        //una vez que hayas terminado tus operaciones
        //"limpiar" los valores de las variables
        //ejemplo
        nvDescripcion = "";
        //similar con el resto de campos
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error al intentar guardar en la base de datos ", e.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando @ViewScoped, los datos seguirán en memoria del bean mientras que el usuario interactúe en la misma vista. Si lo que quiere es limpiar todos los datos (como si hubiera recién ingresado a la página), sugiero lo siguiente:

```
<p:commandButton value="Crear" id="cbCrear" 
action="#{tipodepagoBean.crear()}" update="@([id$=capaMensajes])" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
```

El método *crear()* debe retornar un *String* (como redireccionamiento a una página) para que el bean @ViewScoped sea recreado, de tal forma que todos las variables se inicializan:

```
public String crear() {
  try{
     if(condiciones){
       //código
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Exito Se ingresó el tipo de pago de forma adecuada.", nvDescripcion));
       return "nombrePagina.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"; 
       //Redireccionará a la misma página, el bean será recreado (las variables serán inicializadas)
     }
  } catch (Exception e){
    //código
  }
  return null; //Al retornar null, la vista/bean seguirá igual en caso no se efectúe correctamente el método.
}
```

Espero haya sido de ayuda. 
Quedo atento a cualquier inquietud ;-)